# Image position in TwitterBootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

- I want to make an website by using bootstrap css.
- I want to make the banner (image) to be centered and fit the size of the box
- I want to define the first box (for banner / image) to have only 3 columns, but why whatever I put any different columns number, it always has the same width?
- I want to make running text, below the banner, how to do it?
- I want to make the text "Garuda is Indonesian symbol." is running.

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my  code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-8"> -->

    <div class="row">
      <!-- <div class="center-block" style="width: 100px; background-color:#ccc; "> -->

      <div class="col-md-3 gam1"  style="background-color: #dedef8;box-shadow:
                                         inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444; "> 

        <img src="D:\Website\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\Images\Garuda.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9 center-block" style="background-color: #dedef8;box-shadow:
                                              inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444; ">
      <h4>Here is the running text</h4>
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-9 "  style="background-color: #B18904;
                                       box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444; ">
          <p>Garuda is Indonesian symbol.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap expects the total number of columns in a row to equal 12.  When you tell it to make something 3 columns wide, it still leaves room for the other 9 columns.  You can use offsets to move things over in a row.  For example, "col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" will make the element 3 columns wide and also shift it over three columns to the right.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

The tricky thing with centering something that's 3 columns wide is that the math doesn't work out evenly.  If you offset by 4 columns, it will be too far to the left.  If you offset by 5 columns, it will be too far to the right.  You could make the image 4 columns wide and offset by 4, or you could skip using columns altogether and just center the image by displaying it as a block and setting the margins to auto on both sides.

Here's a quick demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/hnxrxow0/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">    
    <img class="center" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/200px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg" alt="Mona Lisa"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The easiest way to center the text below the picture would be to just put a "text-center" class on that div.  Again, you won't be able to center something that's 9 rows wide using Bootstrap's grid system, because math.

Comment: Sorry - the JS Fiddle should be a link, not a code sample.  SO wouldn't accept it as a link, though.

Comment: Taylor714,  instead of circumventing the jsFiddle policy, you should make the improvments suggested by it.  Answers should contain all the relevant information within the body of the post.  Meaning you should add the relevant jsFiddle code and then creating a working link.  Or better yet, play around with Stack Snippets in page.

Comment: Agreed - just wasn't sure how to go about it. I'll check into Stack Snippets.  Thanks.

Comment: Taylor714, Thanks alot for ur answer. I had followed your instruction by adding class= center to bootstrap.css file in  folder CSS/bootstrap.css. But when I tried to see the result, there was no difference with the first one. I am using adobe dreamweaver and and select "preview in chrome" to see the result. Why it's still same?

Comment: I also tried to change the margin from 0 to be 20 (body {
  margin: 20;} ) But there is no difference. Why? Where I should write the order? In which file? Is it right to write it in CSS/bootstrap.css file?

Comment: To keep things organized and easier to read, you'll want to create a new file for your custom css in the CSS folder, and make sure you link to it from the head tag in your HTML page.  In the HTML file, you'll need to add the "center" class to your image.  Then in your custom CSS file, you can copy and paste the CSS above.  You shouldn't need to adjust the body margins at all, though I would still put the image inside of a row.

Comment: I just edited the HTML sample above to show how you can put it inside of a Bootstrap row and then 12 columns.  That will take care of the body margin for you, and then putting the "center" class on the image will center it within that space.